# retrieving data from NSDictionary , Plist

Tags: objective-c, arrays, xcode4, nsdictionary

Hi i'm fairly new to objC and i am hoping someone can help me out.

I 'm making a sample location app.
It has a plist with locationNames and coordinates. 
i have read the plist into a NSDictionary, i am also using an NSarray with allkeys to return the keys.

Each key contains 2 stings, i want to be able to specifically return 1 of them.

This is my plist:

```
 <dict>
        <key>orleans</key>
        <dict>
            <key>lat</key>
            <string>100192</string>
            <key>lon</key>
            <string>990099</string>
        </dict>
        <key>arras</key>
        <dict>
            <key>lon</key>
            <string>122121</string>
            <key>lat</key>
            <string>878737</string>
        </dict>
 </dict>
```

This is my code:

```
    NSString *myFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] 
                        pathForResource:@"vluchten" ofType:@"plist"];


    coordinaten = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:myFile];
    vluchten    = [coordinaten allKeys];  


    NSLog(@"coordinaat lon :%@" ,[coordinaten objectForKey:[vluchten objectAtIndex:1]]);
```

--
which returns:

```
    2012-06-22 19:39:27.075 Pigeons[6817:11603] coordinaat lon :{
    lat = 100192;
    lon = 990099;
  }
```

And i only want the **lat** value returned (lon i want later)

I hope someone can help me out here please.

Greetings,
jaco

Comment: Think about marking the question as answered :) Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your plist defines a dictionary where each member is also a dictionary, so:

```
NSDictionary *arras = [coordinaten objectForKey:[vluchten objectAtIndex:1]];
NSString *arrasLat = [arras objectForKey:@"lat"];
```